# why is this model giving me a "Value Error"

Tags: numpy, keras

Its giving me a value error that I don't understand. Here is what it says :

> Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays" my data has 8 columns and i m trying to  predict the last 2 for output.

This is a ranking algorithm that I'm experimenting with my own data with :

```
import pandas as pd
import keras
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


from keras import backend

from keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Input, Subtract

from keras.models import Model



INPUT_DIM = 7



# Model.

h_1 = Dense(128, activation="relu")

h_2 = Dense(64, activation="relu")

h_3 = Dense(32, activation="relu")

s = Dense(1)



# Relevant document score.

rel_doc = Input(shape=(INPUT_DIM,), dtype="float32")

h_1_rel = h_1(rel_doc)

h_2_rel = h_2(h_1_rel)

h_3_rel = h_3(h_2_rel)

rel_score = s(h_3_rel)



 # Irrelevant document score.

irr_doc = Input(shape=(INPUT_DIM,), dtype="float32")

h_1_irr = h_1(irr_doc)

h_2_irr = h_2(h_1_irr)

h_3_irr = h_3(h_2_irr)

irr_score = s(h_3_irr)



# Subtract scores.

diff = Subtract()([rel_score, irr_score])



# Pass difference through sigmoid function.

prob = Activation("sigmoid")(diff)



# Build model.

model = Model(inputs=[rel_doc, irr_doc], outputs=prob)

model.compile(optimizer="adadelta", loss="binary_crossentropy")



#  data.
data=pd.read_csv('ranking_dataset_remastered.csv')
print (data.head())
X = data.iloc[:, 1:7]
y = data.iloc[:, 6:7]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 
 0.2)
)

 # Train model.

 NUM_EPOCHS = 20

BATCH_SIZE = 512

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
 epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, verbose=1)



# Generate scores from document/query features.

get_score = backend.function([rel_doc], [rel_score])

get_score([X_train])

get_score([y_train])
```

Comment: Please remove all the unnecessary newlines from your code, add spaces around `=` sign, etc. It's very hard to read.Also tell us what line of code the exception was thrown on; you can highlight it in the code with `# <--- throws ValueError`. Did you look at those input arrays and figure out the list size? Please try to debug it a little, don't just throw a wall of code at us.

Answer (score 0):

When you defined your model with this line:

```py
model = Model(inputs=[rel_doc, irr_doc], outputs=prob)
```

You created what keras refers to as a [multi-input model](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models), which essentially means that your model is expecting **more than one inputs** (in your case 2: `rel_doc` and `irr_doc`).

However during training you are just passing 1 input, `X_train`:

```py
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
                    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, verbose=1)
```

What you should do in order to work is to have **two arrays**, one representing relevant and one irrelevant documents and feed them both to the model during training like this:

```py
history = model.fit([X_rel_train, X_irr_train], y_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
                    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, verbose=1)
```

Comment: well should i have 2 y_train's too then?

Comment: here is what i updated but still value error that " Error when checking input: expected input_25 to have shape (7,) but got array with shape (6,)"                
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#  data.
data=pd.read_csv('ranking_dataset_remastered.csv')

X1 = data.iloc[:9960, 1:7]
y1 = data.iloc[:9960, 6:7]
X2=data.iloc[1:9961,:]
y2=data.iloc[1:9961,6:7]
X1_train, X1_test, y1_train, y1_test = train_test_split(X1, y1, test_size = 
 0.2)
X2_train, X2_test, y2_train, y2_test=train_test_split(X2, y2, test_size=0.2)

Comment: For your first question, no you have two `X_train` because you defined a multi-input model (i.e. has two different input paths). On the other hand, you have defined only one output so you have only one `y_train`. Remember, you must feed the model whatever you previously defined.

Comment: For your second question you need to focus on what the error message says: `expected input_25 to have shape (7,) but got array with shape (6,)` this means that pandas thought it would get an input with 7 features but instead you gave it one with only 6! Either change the the input shape during definition so that it accepts 6 features, or feed it with 7 as it is expecting.

Comment: how do i define same training and 2 different outputs to compare in this model ?i want relevant and irrelevant to be for the output. the input is the same..

Comment: The way it is defined now you subtract the one from the other and apply a sigmoid function to generate a prediction. If you want multiple outputs you should follow [this guide](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models). The feeling I'm getting though is that you don't have a good grasp of what you are trying to accomplish. The first step is understanding what you are trying to do,  i.e. *what are my inputs?*, *what is the shape of each?*, *what are my outputs?*, *what loss function do I want?*, etc. **Then**, you should proceed to implement it!

Comment: ya i needed to read chapter 7 of the chollet book before i started this. now i m getting it. thanks for the comments though ! i m new to keras and i was in the sequential model chapter when i started this ..